# How do I find the count of a column of lists and display by date?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset looks like this [image]

Using python and pandas I want to display the count of each unique item in the coverage column which are stored in a list shown in the table.

I want to display that count by device and by date.

Example out put would be:

[image]

the unique coverage count being the count of each unique list value in the "coverage" row

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` method to iterate over rows and apply a custom function. This function may return the length of the list. For example:

```
df["covarage_count"] = df["coverage"].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

Comment: I like this solution. One problem, len() gives me the number of characters in the list instead of the number of unique instances of "892a10705a7ffff". I need to count each string of characters between " ",

Comment: I thought the cell value was a list. If they are string a solution is to use eval `lambda x: len(eval(x))` however eval is risky if you cannot control the string and it may expose your code to security vulnerabilities. In that case you may use something like parsing as a json

Comment: it is a list of strings, sorry. So each row of the column "coverage" is something like ['89268cd85abffff', '89268cd8507ffff', '89268c... ]. How would I count each string within that list?

Comment: didn't `eval` work? do you have any error using `eval`?

Comment: eval worked perfectly to count. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it using for loops

```
coverage_list = []
for item in list(df["coverage"]):
  if item == '[]':
    item = ''
  else:
    item = list(item.split(","))

  coverage_list.append(len(item))
  # print(len(item))


df["coverage_count"] = coverage_list
```

Comment: when I use this I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: try this line 6, item = (item.split(","))